# Static files in wwwroot is not served in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have files in my `wwwroot` folder like this:

[image]

But still, I'm getting an HTTP "404 - not found" error since the CSS files are not being served.

Even if I try to access it through localhost:

```
http://localhost:58233/Content/css-new
```

The file still causes a http 404 not found.

I did include `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Program.cs`, and I can see the files in the build directory:

[image]

This is weird as I assumed all files in the `wwwroot` folder should be served to public.

What else should I check and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should also check access rights. The file might be unreadable by the user running the webserver.  Or the extension (`css-new` does not seem to have one) might break things.

Comment: When you use IIS, Microsoft invented: [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)

Comment: @Luuk yeah i think you got it right, the ones without extensions are not being served correctly. The other ones are served properly.
How should I served such files?

Comment: What web-server are you using? (and what has `Program.cs` to do with this problem, because you mention it, but you did not share what is being done with it.

Comment: I am still using the built in one in VS2022, so i I assume its the built in IIS,
Anyways thanks to your tip, i figure it out, the solution is to set ServeUnknownFileTypes to true. Thanks for the tip man!